# Reading from XML, for loop issue

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

The code below reads from the XML but the loop runs another time which prints null values.
Im searching inside the root ax, to display the attribute value increment, the first time it displays the correct value but it also runs another time and displays empty string

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <ax>
    <position start="23" increment="2" />
    <config server="127.0.0.1" location="er" />
  </ax>
  <pl>
    <position start="98" y="0.0"  />
    <config server="60" system="pop" />
  </pl>
</config>
```

### Code:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("config.xml");

foreach (XmlElement element in document.SelectNodes("//ax"))
{
    foreach (XmlElement element1 in element)
    {
        string incrementBy = element1.GetAttribute("increment");
        MessageBox.Show(incrementBy);
    }
}
```

First time it displays the right value 2, it runs second time as-well and displays null! It should run once since I have clearly mentioned `SelectNode("//ax")`.

Comment: because there is no second element that contains increment attribute?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to get from config? `increment` attribute value from first child of `ax` element? Is it possible that several children will have `increment` attribute?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes

Comment: @meWantToLearn sorry, added one more question

Comment: Seems both Position and Config are child elements of the ax element. So the second iteration of the foreach loop is due to the config element.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, I should check whether it has the attribute or not

```
     if (element1.HasAttribute("increment"))
                    {
                        string incrementBy = element1.GetAttribute("increment");
                        MessageBox.Show(incrementBy);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this xml with Linq (assume you there can be no child elements with increment attribute):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("config.xml");
var element = xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("ax/*[@increment]");
if (element != null)
{
   int increment = (int)element.Attribute("increment");
   // ...
}
```

Or without XPath:

```
var element = xdoc.Root.Elements("ax").Elements()                      
                  .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("increment") != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all `increment` values, you can do the following using `LINQ to XML`

```
var increments = XDocument.Load("config.xml")
                 .Descendants()
                 .Where(x => x.Attribute("increment") != null)
                 .Select(x=> (string)x.Attribute("increment"));
```